# Atomic Operation in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

typedef struct { int counter; } atomic_t;

what does atomic_t means?  HOW does compiled treats it? Historically, counter has been declared volatile, which implied it's a CPU register right?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is declared as a struct like that is so that the programmer using it is forced (gently reminded, rather) to use the access functions to manipulate it. For example, `aval = 27` would not compile. Neither would `aval++`.

The `volatile` keyword has always meant the opposite of a CPU register: it means a value that has to be read from and written to memory directly.

If `counter` was historically `volatile` it was wrong because `volatile` has never been good enough on its own to ensure proper atomic updates. I believe that the current atomic manipulator functions use a cast through a volatile pointer **combined** with the appropriate write barrier functions, and [machine code for some operations that the compiler cannot do properly](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h).

Comment: thanks for the clarification on volatile.  but how does struct guaranteed to be atomic?

Answer (score 1):

atomic_t indicates it's an atomic type. Compiler will treats it as typedefed struct. I don't know what history says, but volatile is usually used to skip compiler optimizations and it doesn't imply CPU register.

Well, as it's name implies, all of it's operation is atomic i.e done at once, can't be scheduled out. atomic_t types have few helpers (like atomic_{inc,dec}, atomic_or and many) for manipulating any atomic type data. During manipulation of an atomic type, helpers usually inserts *bus lock*, as if they're not interrupted and make the whole thing atomic.

Comment: atomic_t indicates as typedefed struct, so what so special about that? does the compiler knows it can't be scheduled out?  struct by definition doesn't have that.

Comment: You miss the point of inserting bus lock. On x86, there's a lock instruction to lock the system bus. Compiler is nothing just produces object code, compiler doesn't execute code, CPU does. Compiler doesn't need to know it.